# How to normalize a float number between [0,1] range?

Tags: python

I am working on a discriminator which goal is to say if a video that it gets in input is human made or not.
Therefore the output is a value included between 0(false) and 1(true) for each frame; then the final result is going to be the sum of each frame evaluation.
How do I apply the normalization?

And I also have another doubt: should I normalize every frame result and then normalize the sum too or leave the frame results as they are and normalize only the sum?

Comment: Why don't you just compute the mean of values in [0,1] range?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco that can work so thank you for your reply, the problem is that I am following the architecture provided in the paper from which i am replicating the neural network, and it says that the discriminator output is the sum of each frame score (i am not sure if the normalized mean provides the same performances and precision)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply normalization on each frame independently because otherwise a frame in which your model predicts a huge value (because it's very certain for some reason) can ruin the entire prediction (unless you apply some extra mechanism on top of this, see the extra note at the end). As to how to do it, either predict 1 value and apply a function that outputs values between 0 and 1 e.g. a sigmoid function ([Sigmoid function wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function)) or predict 2 values (yes or no probabilities) and then apply softmax ([Softmax function wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function)).

So a direct answer to your question is: apply sigmoid and the value can be treated as a probability because it will be between 0 and 1.

Extra note: You can also try to combine the results of predictions with an RNN or with some attention mechanism